# Is it me or is NSNumberFormatter broken?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

In Swift, I want to convert a String into an NSDecimalNumber useable for arithmetic.

For the vast majority of cases, NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString() works great.  However, for certain values no matter how I go about trying to convert the parsed number to an NSDecimalNumber it does not work correctly.

Check out this output from some playground code I wrote (included below). It demonstrates the issue using one specific value:

```
numberString: 546000.06
numberFormatter.numberFromString(numberString): 546000.0600000001 //expected = 546000.06
number.decimalValue: NSDecimal(_mantissa: (34305, 29756, 26071, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0)) //Need NSDecimalNumber to convert to String, see below
number.doubleValue: 546000.06 //expected = 546000.06
number.floatValue: 546000.0 //expected = 546000.06
** number and numberString converted into NSDecimalNumber different ways **
NSDecimalNumber(string: numberString): 546000.06 //expected = 546000.06
NSDecimalNumber(decimal: number.decimalValue): 546000.0600000001 //expected = 546000.06
NSDecimalNumber(double: number.doubleValue): 546000.0600000001024 //expected = 546000.06
NSDecimalNumber(float: number.floatValue): 546000.0624999999488 //expected = 546000.06
** Add one to each NSDecimalNumber **
stringDecimalNumber+1: 546001.06 // expected = 546000.06+1
decimalDecimalNumber+1: 546001.0600000001 // expected = 546000.06+1
doubleDecimalNumber+1: 546001.0600000001024 // expected = 546000.06+1
floatDecimalNumber+1: 546001.0624999999488 // expected = 546000.06+1
** Formatted NSNumber and NSDecimalNumbers **
number formatted: 546,000.06
stringDecimalNumber formatted: 546,000.06
decimalDecimalNumber formatted: 546,000.0600000001
doubleDecimalNumber formatted: 546,000.0600000001
floatDecimalNumber formatted: 546,000.0624999999
```

**It seems there is no way to get from the NSNumber parsed by the NSNumberFormatter to an accurate NSDecimalNumber.**  Interestingly, passing the numeric String directly to the NSDecimalNumber constructor appears to work perfectly.  Unfortunately, I can't just do that because in my real-world use case the string is a currency so I **need** the NSNumberFormatter.

As promised here is the playground code that generated the output above:

```
import Foundation

let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 10

let numberString: String = "546000.06"

print("numberString: \(numberString)")

let number: NSNumber = numberFormatter.numberFromString(numberString)!
print("numberFormatter.numberFromString(numberString): \(number) //expected = \(numberString)")
print("number.decimalValue: \(number.decimalValue) //Need NSDecimalNumber to convert to String, see below")
print("number.doubleValue: \(number.doubleValue) //expected = \(numberString)")
print("number.floatValue: \(number.floatValue) //expected = \(numberString)")

print("** number and numberString converted into NSDecimalNumber different ways **")
let stringDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: numberString)
let decimalDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: number.decimalValue)
let doubleDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(double: number.doubleValue)
let floatDecimalNumber: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(float: number.floatValue)

print("NSDecimalNumber(string: numberString): \(stringDecimalNumber) //expected = \(numberString)")
print("NSDecimalNumber(decimal: number.decimalValue): \(decimalDecimalNumber) //expected = \(numberString)")
print("NSDecimalNumber(double: number.doubleValue): \(doubleDecimalNumber) //expected = \(numberString)")
print("NSDecimalNumber(float: number.floatValue): \(floatDecimalNumber) //expected = \(numberString)")


print("** Add one to each NSDecimalNumber **")
print("stringDecimalNumber+1: \(NSDecimalNumber.one().decimalNumberByAdding(stringDecimalNumber)) // expected = \(numberString)+1")

print("decimalDecimalNumber+1: \(NSDecimalNumber.one().decimalNumberByAdding(decimalDecimalNumber)) // expected = \(numberString)+1")
print("doubleDecimalNumber+1: \(NSDecimalNumber.one().decimalNumberByAdding(doubleDecimalNumber)) // expected = \(numberString)+1")
print("floatDecimalNumber+1: \(NSDecimalNumber.one().decimalNumberByAdding(floatDecimalNumber)) // expected = \(numberString)+1")

print("** Formatted NSNumber and NSDecimalNumbers **")
print("number formatted: \(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(number)!)")
print("stringDecimalNumber formatted: \(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(stringDecimalNumber)!)")
print("decimalDecimalNumber formatted: \(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(decimalDecimalNumber)!)")
print("doubleDecimalNumber formatted: \(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(doubleDecimalNumber)!)")
print("floatDecimalNumber formatted: \(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(floatDecimalNumber)!)")
```

I haven't seen anything about this on the web really so I want to believe it is me who is at fault.  That said my playground code is dirt simple so I can't see what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Set `generatesDecimalNumbers` to true on your number formatter and `stringFromNumber` will return an `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` doesn't understand that `NSDecimalNumber` is different than common `NSNumber`. It just takes its `doubleValue` and formats it. Basically, you cannot use `NSNumberFormatter` for `NSDecimalNumber` and keep precision.  However, `NSDecimalNumber` has its own methods to convert to string.

Comment: "Is it me or is NSNumberFormatter broken?" If you want to be a successful Cocoa programmer, you should start by assuming it's you. Seriously. What are the chances that this long-established fundamental NSFoundation class is "broken"? And that no one noticed until you fortuitously came along?

Comment: "I can't just do that because in my real-world use case the string is a currency so I need the NSNumberFormatter." - your example doesn't compile if numberString = "$546000.06".

Comment: Yes,  currencies are a problem but you can format a simple number, e.g. `1` or `-1` using `NSNumberFormatter` and then replace the substring "1" with the formatted `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @matt the chances are incredibly slim but it did get you to read my question!

Comment: @dan thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it though and got the same results...

Comment: @Casey in my "real-world use case" I set the NSNumberFormatter numberStyle to .CurrencyStyle

Comment: "it did get you to read my question" Actually I stopped at the _title_ of the question.

Comment: @mkalmes  It is a duplicate of sorts, sorry.  I added this question because I thought it was clearer.  Is there a way to delete the old one or something else I could do?

Comment: @matt I didn't realize the question was so offensive.  As far as I can tell the question is accurate - NSNumberFormatter is either broken or my understanding of it is.  From my example it seems it is not possible to get a usable NSDecimalNumber if I have to rely on an NSNumberFormatter to parse the numeric string.  If that is by design, it's me - if not, it's  broken IMO

Comment: @moliveira Don't worry about it. This questions is already linked to your first questions. It's better to stick with just one question and edit it, if your intent isn't clear.